# Measuring the length of a list with len() gives wrong results

Tags: python

Help! I don't understand this. When I try to measure the length of a list in python 2.7 with len() I get the wrong result.

Here's the code:

```
    if len(fields) > 0:
        fields_split = []

        for i in fields:
            i = i.split(',')
            fields_split.append(i)

        reindz = len(fields_split)
        print fields
        print reindz

        print fields_split
```

Here's the output:

```
[u'name,description']
1
[[u'name', u'description']]
[u'name,description']
1
[[u'name', u'description']]
[u'name,description']
1
[[u'name', u'description']]
[u'name']
1
[[u'name']]
[u'name']
1
[[u'name']]
[u'name']
1
[[u'name']]
```

So even though the split call works there are no differences in length between lists containing one and two elements ...

Comment: your list  contains a string with a comma in it, at first glance. Also, I think the problem is your line `i = i.split()`. It probably messes up the loop

Comment: Your list has only one item in it which is another list with two items.

Comment: look at the first line after each number - that's the output of print fields_split and it does contain two strings [[u'name', u'description']] right? that's where the problem is ...

Comment: You're calling `len` on the outer list. The outer list only contains one element, `[u'name', u'description']`. Now if you call `len` on the INNER LIST, you'll see two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per split string, you are *appending* the resulting list to `fields_split`. So `fields_split` will always have the exact same number of elements as `fields` has, each element a separate list object. Those separate list objects will each have 1 or more strings.

If you wanted all the split strings to be added to `fields_split` without the intermediate list, use `list.extend()` rather than `list.append()`:

```
fields_split.extend(i)
```

Now each split result is added as a separate entry in `fields_split` directly, and the length will either be equal to or greater than the length of `fields`.

Answer (score 1):

Based off your outputs

```
[u'name,description']
1
[[u'name', u'description']]
[u'name,description']
1
...
```

The `len()` function returns the correct output. For the second example above, `[[u'name', u'description']]` has length of 1 because it is a 2D list. The first "dimension" is a list. There is only 1 of those in that dimension. So the length of that is 1. The length of the 2nd "dimension" (that inner list) is 2, because it has two items in it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this..

```
fields=u'name,description'
if len(fields) > 0:
    fields_split = fields.split(',')
    reindz = len(fields_split)
    print fields
    print reindz
    print fields_split
```

Result:

```
name,description
2
[u'name', u'description']
```